# Under what conditions might you end your move in another creature's space?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, movement, grapple, stealth

In the section on combat, the PHB p191 says "*Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can’t willingly end your move in its space.*"

Even in combat, are there specific rules that override this general rule?  For instance:

- While grappling or restraining a creature.
- Or hiding behind a creature.
- Or if you just run out of movement and there you are.

Comment: The questions seems broad to me. Each part of your second paragraph can be posted as a separate question (and probably has been). As for the question "_Under what conditions_", the rules you quoted seem to auto-answer it : you can when it's not deliberate (i.e. when you don't willingly trying to do so).

Comment: And I should read my comments over before posting them : question*; when you're not*. Sorry.

Comment: I think the question is actually a useful one, not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: Been awhile, but I think I asked in part because of the grappling.  Still seems like a legit question to me.

Comment: I think this is a good question, I'm just not sure what the question is.  The _title_ asks when you might end your move in another creature's space, and the answer to that is **many** different reasons that have to do with unplanned forcing the end of your movement or your turn.  The _question_ asks whether there is an exception to the general rule that you can't _willingly_ end your turn in another creature's space, and to that I can think of only **one** exception.  Which is your actual question?

Answer (score 2):

### If you didn't choose to be.

Your quoted passage from the PHB actually says it all, you cannot choose to do it even *incidentally*. So this means you can't incidentally run out of movement in a creature's space.

While grappled, another creature is moving you *against your will* so you can end your turn inside another creature's space if the grappler decides to do it.

---

As a general rule for RPGs, though:

### Things *can* and *will* get weird.

Players will come up with the most insa- *creative* ideas and you have to be prepared to rule on what makes sense to you.

Remember the GM governs the rules, not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

### The key word is *willingly*

As you quote, the rule about movement says

> Whether a creature is a friend or an enemy, you can’t **willingly end** your move in its space

"End" even [extends to a short stop to do something](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/79814/what-happens-when-allies-occupy-the-same-space), before moving on.

In summary can you end your move in another creature's space?

1. You **can if you did not move willingly**
2. You **can if your DM allowed you to climb upon a bigger creature**
3. You **cannot by grappling or hiding**
4. You **cannot by running out of movement**

#### Unwilling movement

There are many ways you *can* end your turn in another creature's space, all of which work by not you moving *willingly*, but someone else moving you, you moving unwillingly, or you being stopped there. For example:

- You can be **shoved** into another creatures space
- You can be **teleported** into another creatures space
- You get **pulled** into the other creatures space, [for example by Thorn Whip](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/164987/can-a-druid-pull-a-target-through-other-creatures-with-thorn-whip)
- You can be **enlarged** or polymorphed to [become larger and overlap](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107469/what-happens-when-you-end-up-sharing-an-enemy-or-friends-space-due-to-a-size) with another creatures space
- You are **stopped** that is, your [movement is reduced to zero](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105393/what-happens-when-your-movement-is-set-to-zero-while-attempting-to-move-through) by someone else, while you are in another creature's space
- You **fall unwillingly** into a pit that contains another creature
- You get **engulfed** by a Gelatinous Cube
- You are **swallowed** by a Purple Worm
- ... and so on ...

In nearly all of these cases, once you can act again, you likely [need to move out of the creatures space if you can, or it out of yours](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/105393/what-happens-when-your-movement-is-set-to-zero-while-attempting-to-move-through), if its turn happens first, although this is up to DM adjudication. (The main question is do you "end your move" in its space if you do not move at all?)

#### Climbing onto a Bigger Creature

The only exception to this rule I am aware of is the optional action **Climb Onto A Bigger Creature** (DMG, p. 271), which allows you to willingly share a space with a bigger opponent by climbing onto it:

> If it wins the contest, the smaller creature successfully moves into the target creature's space and clings to its body. While in the target's space, the smaller creature moves with the target and has advantage on attack rolls against it.
> The smaller creature can move around within the larger creature's space, treating the space as difficult terrain.

#### Running out of movement

[You cannot take actions](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153447/does-the-rule-that-you-cannot-willingly-end-your-move-in-another-creatures-spac), if they would leave you ending in another creatures space, so **you cannot "run out of movement"**, and if your move would lead to such an outcome, your DM can ask you to reformulate how you move, or retcon what happend (if there already were opportunity attacks etc.).

#### Grappling and Hiding

**Grappling** in 5e will not let you share a space with the grappled creature, all it does (PHB p. 195, Grappling) is to subject the target to the *grappled* condition, which sets its speed to 0 and makes it impossible for it to benefit from a bonus to speed. It by default still stays in the adjacent space.

**Hiding** (on p. 177 PHB) is achieved by a Dexterity (Stealth) check, it has nothing to do with moving. There are rules how moving towards opponents in combat might blow your hidden status, but there is nothing whatsoever about moving into another creature's space, so this won't help.

Answer (score -2):

The DMG mentions being in a creatures space in the section titled "Climb onto a bigger creature"

I seem to recall somewhere else where it talks about falling prone in another creatures space, but I cannot be sure.

Answer (score -2):

A creature can fly above another, end its turn and lose flying. Similarly a monk can run along a wall, get one an opponent and end his turn thereby falling.

I think falling by however they got above the other character or creature would be the only way.